# How to find daily average over a time period in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've a table where there's two column:

**MARKS**

**CREAT_TS**

I want to daily average marks for between two date range (e.g. startDate & endDate)

I've made the following query:

```
select SUM(MARKS)/ COUNT(date(CREAT_TS)) AS DAILY_AVG_MARKS, 

date(CREAT_TS) AS DATE 

from TABLENAME

group by date(CREAT_TS)
```

With this query I can get the daily average only if there's a row in the database for the date. But my requirement is that even if there's no row, I want to show 0 for that date.
I mean I want the query to return X rows if there are X days between (startDate, endDate)

Can anyone help me. :(

Comment: How do you define **startDate** and **endDate**? Are they parameters, MIN and MAX of `creat_ts`, or something else?

Comment: You may want to build a **calendar table** and then perform an **OUTER JOIN**. See http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Comment: Note that `AVG(MARKS)` will work just as well

Comment: @PM77-1, They can be any timestamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a set of integers that you can add to the dates.  The following will give you an idea:

```
select thedate, avg(Marks) as DAILY_AVG_MARKS
from (select startdate+ interval num day as thedate
      from (select d1.d + 10 * d2.d + 100*d3.d as num
            from (select 0 as d union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                  select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
                 ) d1 cross join
                 (select 0 as d union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                  select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
                 ) d2 cross join
                 (select 0 as d union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                  select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
                 ) d3
            ) n cross join
            (select XXX as startdate, YYY as enddate) const
       where startdate + num <= enddate
      ) left outer join
      tablename t
      on date(CREAT_TS) = thedate
group by thedate
```

All the complication is in creating a set of sequential dates for the report.  If you have a `numbers` table or a `calendar` table, then the SQL looks much simpler.

How does this work?  The first big subquery has two parts.  The first just generates the numbers from 0 to 999 by cross joining the digits 0-9 and doing some arithmetic.  The second joins this to the two dates, `startdate` and `enddate` -- you need to put the correct values in for XXX and YYY.  With this table, you have all the dates between the two values.  If you need more than 999 days, just add in another cross join.

This is the left joined to your data table.  The result is that all dates appear for the group by.

In terms of reporting, there are advantages and disadvantages to doing this in the presentation layer.  Basically, the advantage to doing it in SQL is that the report layer is simpler.  The advantage to doing it in the reporting layer is that the SQL is simpler.  It is hard for an outsider to make that judgement.

My suggestion would be to create a numbers table that you can just use in reports like this.  Then the query will look simpler and you won't have to change the reporting layer.

Comment: What do you mean by numbers table or calendar table? The datatype of the creat_ts column?

Comment: Please avoid using nested queries.

Comment: @hilarudeens, Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: @LittleLebowski . . . `creat_ts` is a column in *your* question.  A numbers table contains just a bunch of integers.  A calendar table contains dates with information about the dates -- a very useful table for most purposes.

Comment: @hilarudeens . . . You shouldn't spout such non-sense without backing it up.

Comment: Hey Why you get anger. I am just saying, nested queries slow down system response. I am not saying that your query is wrong. Cool

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Can you kindly explain the answer a bit. I'm unable to make it out. How does it work?

Comment: @hilarudeens . . . There is nothing wrong with subqueries.  They are a very important part of the SQL language.  If you learned otherwise, then you need to learn more about databases.  I guess my reaction was in part to the idea that someone would downvote a basically correct answer because of misinformation.

Comment: It is worth noting that MySQL can do some funny things when you use `Date + integer`, ([example here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8311)), and it is advisable to explicitly state the interval, `Date + INTERVAL integer DAY`([Example here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8309))

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Okay i hope that you can give better solution for this. LittleLebowski- Your question is good. I am also waiting for answer

Comment: @GarethD . . . Thank you for that information.  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: While I was at it I made a [working example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1846a/1). To show this is the right way to go about it (if not using a permanent calendar table)

Comment: This is working like a charm. And well explained. Just wanted to ask if this is the best way to generate a report or should I simply use my original query and get the values for the days that exist in the db & then in Java run a loop to create the final list. Which will be more optimal?